# Compiling Mathlink Code in Visual Studio 2010 Express LNK2019 Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, wolfram-mathematica, mathlink

I'm attempting to compile a simple C file for use with Mathematica. (Note: I did follow the rest of the instructions, creating the empty addtwotm.c file and adding addtwo.tm)

```
#include "mathlink.h"
extern int addtwo( int i, int j);

int addtwo( int i, int j)
{
    return i+j;
}

#if WINDOWS_MATHLINK

#if __BORLANDC__
#pragma argsused
#endif

int PASCAL WinMain( HINSTANCE hinstCurrent, HINSTANCE hinstPrevious, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
char  buff[512];
char FAR * buff_start = buff;
char FAR * argv[32];
char FAR * FAR * argv_end = argv + 32;

hinstPrevious = hinstPrevious; /* suppress warning */

if( !MLInitializeIcon( hinstCurrent, nCmdShow)) return 1;
MLScanString( argv, &argv_end, &lpszCmdLine, &buff_start);
return MLMain( (int)(argv_end - argv), argv);
}

#else

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
return MLMain(argc, argv);
}

#endif
```

However, on build, I get this output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: addtwo, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Performing Custom Build Tools
1>  on "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\VC\bin\mprep.exe" "" -o "D:\Applications\Mathematica\SystemFiles\Links\MathLink\DeveloperKit\Windows\MathLinkExamples\addtwo\addtwo\..\addtwotm.c"
1>addtwo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MLMain referenced in function _WinMain@16
1>addtwo.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MLInitializeIcon referenced in function _WinMain@16
1>D:\Applications\Mathematica\SystemFiles\Links\MathLink\DeveloperKit\Windows\MathLinkExamples\addtwo\Debug\addtwo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've followed all provided instructions from Wolfram's MathLink Developer Guide, and made sure to add "ml32i3m.lib" to Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies. Supposedly the ml32/ml64 lib files contain the information for MlMain. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: The error suggests that you did not link the `ml32i3m.lib` during the compiling. Are you sure that VS can *find* the `ml32i3m.lib` because only adding it as dependency shouldn't be enough. You could follow the instructions in the subsection [CompilerAdditions Installation for Microsoft Compilers](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathLinkDeveloperGuide-Windows.html).